# What makes this a community wiki?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, community-wiki, stack-overflow-history

What's special with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22909717/5825294)? Why is it a wiki? I've read through [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/335205), but it didn't really help me understand.

---

Yeah, I've recently answered to that question and got 1 upvote, so it's not a big deal, but I've just dreamt of many upvotes on that very answer :D

Comment: Historically users could choose for their own questions to be CW, and the post timeline suggests that's what happened so.... because OP wanted it to be one?

Comment: Back in 2014, posts were automatically converted to "Community Wiki" if the author edited them too many times. That was later determined to be a misfeature, and it was removed. I've also gone ahead and removed the wiki status on the linked question because it's *clearly* not a wiki (it's only ever had one author).

Comment: So historically there was no requirement for a question/answer to be eligible as a CW?

Comment: It was not a manual wiki-fication, @Nick.

Comment: There were indeed no requirements, indeed originally it was _enforced_ in some circumstances as Cody suggested (10 edits by the author for example, although in this case it appears it was the _11th_ edit)

Comment: @CodyGray, something tells me I won't get my +10 rep, am I correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "requirement ... to be eligible". There's no requirement now. Just various ways that a post can be assigned Community Wiki status. Back in 2014, there was another way: multiple edits. That way has been removed, but the CW status wasn't retroactively removed from posts.

Comment: And the reputation _will_ be recalculated as if the post were never a CW, you'll get your rep

Comment: Your +10 from what? The upvote on your answer to that question? Yeah, you should. I also removed the CW status from all answers, in addition to the question, so everyone should get a windfall of rep from that. (You're welcome! ;-)) But you'll have to wait until rep is recalculated.

Comment: I thought of something like "the question must be answerable in several alternative ways". A bit like the questions asking how to start learning a language.

Comment: Ah, no. CW doesn't mean "answerable in different ways" or anything to do with the *content*. These days, it literally means "intended to be edited by everyone", without any notion of original authorship (and thus no need to preserve author's intent when editing).

Comment: "Community Wiki", as it is named, is really intended for collaborative work, and thus it also reduces the requirement for full edit privilege to a mere 100-rep. Unfortunately, the real purpose of CW is rarely applied and instead, misused.